# How to reduce the width of columns in html table

Tags: html

i want to decrease the width of columns in below table.

```
  <table cellspacing="0"cellpadding="0">
  <tr><td><h3>Allow Points+Cash  </h3></td></tr>
   <tr><td><br>MIN CASH REQUIRED</td></tr>
    <tr>
   <td><br><input type="number" style="width:150px" > &nbsp; Or</td>
   <td><br><input type="number" style="width:150px" > % &nbsp;&nbsp;  Of Award Value</td>
    </tr>
     <tr><td><h3>Point to Cash Conversion </h3></td></tr>
      <tr><td><br>CURRENCY</td>
       <td><br>CONVERSION</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Did you try setting `cellspacing` to 0?

Comment: which columns you are talking about? Please be specific.

Comment: i want to reduce space between all columns in atable

Comment: @steve,yea i tried cellspacing.

Comment: show us the whole HTML and the applicable CSS. Maybe the problem is in there

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
*{ margin:0; padding:0;}
</style>
```

You can remove all the margin and padding using the mentioned code in stylesheet.

Comment: <div style="background-color:white;margin-left:20%;height:auto;width:800px">
<div style="background-color:lightblue;height:60px;padding:1px;padding-left:30px; color:white"><h3>Award Policies</h3></div>
<div id="c9"><img src="images/Assets/compleated.png" ng-show="userForm4.$valid" /></div>
<div style="padding:20px;padding-top:20px">

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're wanting to collapse the borders? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```